# Can i fix launch.json from vs code?

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

Whell, i'm having this problem since i dowloaded VS code, so it was a few days ago. The problem is when i'm tring to debug a "script" with C, it show up a problem with the launch.json. I think is very common and of course many people do it. I show my launch.json:
PD: yes, i do downloaded minGW

```
{
// Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
// Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
// For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "gcc.exe - Compilar y depurar el archivo activo",
        "type": "cppdbg",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}\\VS-Code\\Uso de condicionales.exe",
        "args": [],
        "stopAtEntry": false,
        "cwd": "C:/MinGW/bin",
        "environment": [],
        "externalConsole": true,
        "MIMode": "gdb",
        "miDebuggerPath": "C:\\MinGW\\bin",
        "setupCommands": [
            {
                "description": "Habilitar la impresión con sangría para gdb",
                "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                "ignoreFailures": true
            },
            {
                "description": "Establecer tipo de desensamblado en Intel",
                "text": "-gdb-set disassembly-flavor intel",
                "ignoreFailures": true
            }
        ],
        "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: gcc.exe compilar archivo activo ver(1)"
    }
]
}
```

Comment: "it show up a problem with the launch.json" what is the problem?

Comment: What is the c code ?